# How to clone div wrap on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, insert

http://jsfiddle.net/TDmRv/1/

**What I want to do:** I want the div with the id "theDiv" to be wrapped around the text that gets inputted onto the page. I want this so the text will appear in multiple divs that are created.

**Explained more:**
Okay, so what I am trying to do is type some input in and have it display with in a div- that works fine, but I want the div to wrap around it when I click input. So every time I click "add" the text gets wrapped into a div and is displayed. BUT I am also trying to make this appear multiple times, so every time I add input the div is wrapped around the text. Finally I am trying to have those two buttons placed into there, I assume those would have to be inserted when "add" is clicked with jQuery. I just need some guidance because I am struggling to comprehend how this will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#edit").click(function(){
    $("#theDiv").css("background-color","red");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#delete").click(function(){
    $("#theDiv").remove();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
    $('#edit').wrap('<div class="theDiv" />');
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#theDiv {   
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); 
    margin: 5px 0pt; 
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: blue;
    height:50px;
    }
button {
    float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="hold">
<button id="edit">Edit</button><button id="delete">Delete</button>
</div>
<form>
    <div><textarea class="textI" id="textI2" style="width: 400px; height: 50px;"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="button" id="add"value="add" onclick="theDiv_append()" /></div>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
$('.textI').each(function() {
    var default_value = this.value;
    $(this).focus(function() {
        if(this.value == default_value) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
});
function theDiv_append() {
    $('#theDiv').append($('#textI2').val());
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, each time a user presses "ADD" you want a full new blue div to be displayed with the delete and edit buttons?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I am trying to do. I am have trouble comprehending exactly how to do it.

Comment: Also, you don't need to wrap each jquery function in a `$(document).ready(function() {`, nor do you need to load both the minified and non-minified versions of jquery at the same time.

Comment: Do you want something like this behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/GdSBB/9/

Comment: @GARR like this? http://jsfiddle.net/TDmRv/2/

Comment: Yes, Jeemusu and jcolebrand! That is just want I wanted. But now the hard part, how do I make it so the edit and delete buttons works for each individual div?

Comment: There seems to have been some problems with jsfiddle since yesterday, sometimes I get errors returned back from the sites framework.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TDmRv/22/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this , change #add click to this , it works in jsfiddle, just add the text, I didn't do that , but you will see how to add new blue div

```
            $("#add").click(function(){
             var newRow = $('#theDiv').clone();
             $('#hold').append(newRow);
             $('#edit').wrap('<div class="theDiv" />');
               });
           });
```

Comment: But now comes the question, how do I make the edit and delete work?

Comment: Hmm also, it clones it so the text stays the same from the last one... darn, that's not right.

Comment: that is because there is nothign unique about #theDiv , I just gave example of how to clone

Comment: you should identiy by class, then do .clone().removeclass()  that you used to identify it , so you don't get confused , then you DOM "parent element and child" element selectors to delete and do what ever you want

Comment: I think you probably need to look up the jQuery api for the exact behaviour you're looking for. It will depend on what elements you already have, and how you want them created.

Comment: you should google "jQuery .clone examples"  we can't write the whole thing for you , but that is the right direction

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/TDmRv/8/ .To delete, you need to use the jquery `.on()` operator, because the element your deleting was created after the dom loaded. Then it's just a simple `$(this).parent('div').remove();'

Comment: You guys are too great, thank you for explaining all this for me; it makes sense now how it works. I think I can figure out the colour changing part. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Also, note that i changed your `id=""` attributes to `class=""` . Id's should be a unique value; there should not be multiple id's with the same value on a page.

Comment: Yes, I really need to stop using ID all the time. I need to keep it in my head "ID just one, class everything". Thanks.